# Artin exercise 3.2: $a + b = \text{prime} \implies \gcd(a,b) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following problem from Artin's book.

> Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers whose sum is a prime $p$, their greatest common divisor is $1$.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $d = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$. Then $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$, so $d \mid a + b = p$. As $a,b > 0$, $d > 0$, and $p$ is prime, we have $d = p$ or $d = 1$. If $d = p$, then  $p \mid a$ and $p \mid b$, so $a, b \geq p$ so $a + b \geq 2p > p$, which is a contradiction. So we have $d = 1$, as required.

I think I can take the existence of the $\mathrm{gcd}$ for granted. Since $a$, $b$ and $p$ are prime, we know that $p \mid a$ implies $p \leq a$ and similarly for $b$, but if $p > 0$, $2p > 0$. If one of these numbers weren't positive, this above proof would surely break down.

How does this look?

Comment: Looks like a champ to me, +1.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/if-the-sum-of-positive-integers-a-and-b-is-a-prime-their-gcd-is-1-proof#181508

Comment: "If one of these numbers weren't positive, this above proof would surely break down."  Be worth figuring what would happen and if the statement would still be true.... we still have $d|p$ so $d=1,p$ and if $d=p$ we have $a=kp$ and $b=hp$ for some integers $k,h$ and so $a+b = (h+k)p$ and $h+k = 1$.  Several ways that is possible but they would all involve $a=kp$ and $b=(1-k)p$.... this leads to a slightly alternate proof: Do everything the same and id $d=p$ then $a=kp$ and $b=hp$ so $kp+hp=p$ and $k+h=1$ where $k,h$ are both positive.  Impossible.